# c++ mystery character after string in fgets

Tags: php, c++, arrays, fgets

I have a program the upchucks a mystery 'y' in its output and it appears string related.
What the code does is, it captures buffer data from a php script and 'will be' inserting it into an array. But this mystery 'y' showed up.
My code does what it is supposed to, minus the mystery 'y'.

output:

```
198397652
22014-11-14 15:10:10
Buy
y0.00517290  <- that 'y'
0.00100000
0.00100000
0.00000517
198397685
52014-11-14 15:10:13
Buy
y0.00517290   <- again
0.00100000
0.00100000
0.00000517
198398295
52014-11-14 15:11:14
Buy
y0.00517290  <- another one
0.00100000
0.00100000
0.00000517
```

code:

```
char getmyData()
{
        char buff[BUFSIZ];
        FILE *fp = popen("php getMyorders.php 155", "r");
        if (fp == NULL) perror ("Error opening file");
        while(fgets(buff,sizeof(BUFSIZ),fp)){
                for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(buff) / sizeof(BUFSIZ); ++i) {
                        std::cout << buff[i];
                }
        }
}
```

script:

```
$result = api_query("myorders", array("marketid" => $id));
foreach( $result['return'] as $x) {
        if(is_array($x)) {
                foreach($x as $y) {
                        echo $y . "\n";
                }
        } else {
                echo $x . "\n";
        }
}
```

output of script which c++ captures (minus 'y'):

```
198397652
2014-11-14 15:10:10
Buy
0.00517290
0.00100000
0.00100000
0.00000517
198397685
2014-11-14 15:10:13
Buy
0.00517290
0.00100000
0.00100000
0.00000517
198398295
2014-11-14 15:11:14
Buy
0.00517290
0.00100000
0.00100000
0.00000517
```

How do I get rid of the 'y'?
What is my error?

Comment: I don't see it, but I notice that the 'y' characters are not the only initial characters that show up only in the bad output.  The date strings have digits prepended.

Comment: `sizeof(buff) / sizeof(BUFSIZ)` is probably not what you want.

Comment: should just be `sizeof buff` for the `fgets` argument, then `cout << buff;` - the NUL terminator will ensure the right amount of output is performed, whereas with your current code you assume the entire buffer has been read into....

Comment: output with (buff)/(buff), then (BUFSIZ)/(BUFSIZ), and then (buff)/(BUFSIZ)  https://bpaste.net/show/364e9dabef86  the 3rd try looks the best.

Comment: Why are you using fgets in c++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`buff` is guaranteed to be properly null-terminated, so it can be output directly provided the correct `size` argument is passed to `fgets()`. If you insist on going character by character then simply loop while the element in `buff` is not equal to NUL, i.e. `buff[i] != '\0'`.

Comment: Of what? Of `cout << buff;` or of `for (int i = 0; buff[i] != '\0'; ++i)`?

Comment: ... Why are you doing both?